# What is compatible incompatible objects in java?

Tags: java, object

What is compatible/incompatible objects in java?

Comment: what do you mean? equal/not equal?

Comment: or are you talking about inheritence and interfaces?

Comment: In what sense ? assigning one object reference to another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you meant `comparable` instead of `compatible`? Then...

In common sense, comparable objects are objects of the same "kind". The ones you can compare with each other in some meaningful way.

For example, you can compare one building to another building by variety of factors: by height -- is one higher than other, by total area of building's space, or, for more unusual example, by length of it's stairs.

Generally, you set the rules about how you going to compare objects. Just make sure that these rules are consistent (they give sensible answer when applied to any instance of your comparable objects):

- Object can be compared to itself;
- Comparing A to B gives the same result as comparing B to A;
- If object A compared to B, and B compared to C and both comparisons gave same result, than A compared to C must give the same result;

That's about common sense in general.

In Java this notion can be expressed by making some type, for example, `Building`, implementing interface `Comparable`. That interface expresses the very same notion of comparison as outlined above.

Objects of `Comparable` type must comply with above rules.

What this notion gives you? If your objects can be compared in accordance to above rules and they support `Comparable` interface, you can sort collection of these objects! And you won't need to write sorting algorithm by yourself, since Java implemented it already!

As you noted in Buildings example, buildings can be compared meaningfully not only by their height, but by their total area, for example. Since `Comparable` objects can express only one kind of comparison naturally, you need to use some other way to compare buildings differently. This way provided by `Comparator` interface which expresses same notion, but external to compared objects, so it can be implemented in different ways -- you can have `Comparator` for total area, another for lenght of stairs, etc.

For rather lengthy example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class Building implements Comparable<Building> {
    final int height, totalArea;
    final String name;

    Building(int height, int totalArea, String name) {
        this.height = height;
        this.totalArea = totalArea;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int compareTo(Building o) {
        if (height < o.height) return -1;
        if (height == o.height) return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Building{" +
                "height=" + height +
                ", totalArea=" + totalArea +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Building> buildings = Arrays.asList(
                new Building(100, 5000, "Medium"),
                new Building(250, 3000, "Very tall"),
                new Building(50, 4000, "Short"),
                new Building(150, 3500, "Tall")
                );
        // sort as defined by Object itself -- by height
        Collections.sort(buildings);
        System.out.println(buildings);

        // sort by providing explicit order criteria -- total area
        Collections.sort(buildings, new Comparator<Building>() {
            public int compare(Building o1, Building o2) {
                if (o1.totalArea < o2.totalArea) return -1;
                if (o1.totalArea == o2.totalArea) return 0;
                return 1;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(buildings);
    }
}
```

Finally, non-comparable objects -- these are objects of different kind, which can not be compared naturally. People speak about such attempts "don't compare apples with oranges", or something like that.

Although, if you can come up with a way to compare apples to oranges for your purpose which will comply with 3 rules outlined at the top, you are good to go!

Answer (score 2):

Mainly compatible/incompatible object is relation to serialization. Might be below link is useful for you..

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility is a context used in regard to Objects of different classes in java. Object of a class Car cannot be compared with an object of class Animal.

Thus, if you try to do any operations like casting object of a type to another, it will say that the operation is unsuccessful as the objects are not compatible.